# Doctrine:generate-migrations-diff symfony 1.4

Tags: doctrine, migration, symfony-1.4

I'm having some problems with doctrine-migration.
Changed the code in my *schema.yml* to add a new column:

`filesAttached: {type: array}`

After that, I ran `doctrine:generate-migrations-diff`, and although the message says *"Generated migration classes successfully from difference"* and a temporary *doctrine_schema.yml* is created, there is no migration class under my */lib/migration/doctrine* folder.

Even if I try to run `doctrine:migrate`, it tells me that my migration is at the latest version.
I've used migrations before (2 days ago, I think) and everything worked just fine.
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the auto generated migrations sometimes behave in such way (I never felt like diving into it and finding the reason).

What I would suggest if you have some other migrations classes is to write your own classes based on what you have. Just remember to change the class name to the next version number and give the file a name which is "greater" than the last file you have.

E.g. if you have class `version_3` in file `version3_334455.php` just name it `version_4` and put in `version4_334456.php`.

As to the syntax of the migration you should use this shouldn't be very difficult to figure it out based on the files you already have generated.

Comment: It's what I ended up doing, but then if I tried to migrate --down, it gave me the following error:  
- Could not find migration class for migration step: 6
Renaming the class with a greater number did the trick though :D
Thanks! :)